# Horner's Algorithm with recursion returning wrong result

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Horner's recursive algorithm for fractional part - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444587/horners-recursive-algorithm-for-fractional-part-java)

I am writing a program for Horne'r Algorithm, and I will be honest, I do not have much experience with recursion. I have this method set up to accept a fraction only (there is another method which accepts and returns the whole number) and it will return the result converted from base 'r' to base 10.  I am unsure why, but the method does not seem to be going through the final iteration. Any suggestions as to what I need to do to correct this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
(ex: c = 011, xFinal = 2, i = 2)
Expected answer = .375
Actual answer returned = .75

public static double getHornerFraction(long[] c, int xFinal, int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return ((double)c[i])/xFinal; 
    }
    return (getHornerFraction(c, xFinal, i-1) + c[i])/xFinal;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the Mathematical formula you are trying to implement via recursion? I'm not familiar with Horner's Algorithm and wiki was not that helpful :D

Comment: I had the same issue, so I just inferred the algorithm from what the OP expected.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be the same Kwariz. That problem deals with forgetting to divide by the base, not for getting the recursive direction wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at what you specified and what you expect, I think the problem is that you are walking the array `c` in the wrong direction or otherwise specifying it incorrectly. I think that what you want to do is actually walk the array from index `0` to `c.length`.

```
public static double getHornerFraction(long[] c, int xFinal, int i) {
    if (i == c.length) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (getHornerFraction(c, xFinal, i+1) + c[i])/xFinal;
}
```

Call the above function with `c = {0,1,1}, xFinal = 2, i = 0` and it should give what you expect.

Comment: This gives the expected result certainly.

Comment: Thanks Tim Bender. You were spot on. Your help was greatly appreciated